# Can I drill another set of holes in my studs to mount a TV?

Tags: walls, mounting, studs

I currently have a 47 inch TV which is mounted onto studs in my wall which is good.

But now I plan to get 70 inch TV which means my existing wall mount frame must move a little upwards to fit above the fireplace.

So, I am thinking to take off the existing screws and drill another set of holes a little above the existing holes.

Is it OK to drill multiple holes in the studs?

Comment: What distance will there be between the old and new holes? What size screws does the TV mount use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes. It's OK**

Mounting holes do not significantly affect the strength/function of studs (within reason - if you make Swiss cheese out of them, you might manage to have an effect - but that's not what you are describing.) If you are going to be very close (1/4" or less) to the old holes, you may need to drill them out and glue in a dowel before you drill the new holes - if further away, no need.